# Develop a system to differentiate laser pointers from the ambient light based on the information collected by two arrays of digital FPA detectors

Tags: computers, laser, optics, ccd

I would like to develop a system to differentiate laser pointers from
the ambient light  based on the information collected by two arrays of digital FPA detectors embedded inside the cavity of a commercial airliner windows including the cockpit.
   The principles of operation of the digital FPAs are described in this article,   Kelly, M. W. and Blackwell, M. H., “Digital-pixel FPAs enhance infrared imaging capabilities,” Laser Focus World 49(1), 90 (2013).

The first array of FPA detectors measures the HSV color saturation by converting 24 bit RGB color depths.  The second array of FPA detectors measures the spectral bandwidth after the incoming light wavefront is projected onto a diffraction grating.

Saturation is how pure the color is from spectral point of view. 
For example, a laser has a very narrow spectrum, which implies high saturation.

If a laser has high saturation, is the converse true? 
In other words , If I measure RGB and convert to HSV, 
Does high saturation imply that it must originate from a coherent laser source? 
the answer to the previous question is not necessarily a laser. 
But it's hard to have a saturated color with a wide spectrum, 
since the wider it is, the harder it is to have a high response in only one component.

Is it feasible to develop such a system for differentiating laser pointers from
the ambient light? If so, what might be the design parameters be for it?

Comment: Have you looked at the spectrums of commonly found high intensity ambient light sources such as various types of discharge lamps, LEDs (both white and RGB types) and such like?

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, Thank you for your comment.I just found out that LEDs emit light that is pretty much monochromatic, as do low pressure sodium lights.   Are there distinguishing characteristics of coherent laser pointers which one could use  to tell laser pointer beams apart from the overall image observed through a Boeing 737 airline cockpit window?

Comment: Aside from coherency, the exact wavelengths are probably a fairly good indication, but I guess detecting coherence ..http://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/2670/1/2670.pdf might be the best approach.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, Thank you for your recommendation. I am starting to read the pdf you attached. I will get back to you after I read it. If you wish, please answer this question.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany, I just read your cited pdf.How could it be modified to isolate on the exact pixels which comprise the detected coherent laser pointer? Does the piezoelectric transducer which is used to find the location of the frequency spike have a fast enough response time necessary for almost realtime filtering of coherent light sources? Thank you.

Comment: Funnily, I found this question when searching *"Saturation is how pure the color is from spectral point of view. For example, a laser has a very narrow spectrum, which implies high saturation."* from [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/4861/17653) to check if it came from a source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could likely make as effective a laser-pointer detection using a less "high-tech" approach, simply by detecting the "nearly collimated" beam pattern of a laser.

If you trade out your high-tech (and price) sensor arrrays for simpler detector 'screens' that simply register basic intensity & peak color on each pixel; then there will be incredibly few non-laser light sources that will project onto nearly identically sized small areas of any 2 screens with more than a few mm of separation between them.

I.E. Shining even a "tightly focused" LED "flashlight" onto 2 screens spaced 40mm apart will either produce a significantly larger "bright spot" on the further screen than on the nearer one, or will simply illuminate the entirety of both screens. Meanwhile, a laser 'beam' striking either screen will project nearly an identical 'spot' on both screens, so any "spot" that appears at similar size & brightness on both screens is <95% likely to be from a laser source (or at least a very expensive imitation of a laser, producing a similarly collimated [and destructive] output).

Comment: Your answer is great. The reason I am starting this project is to filter visible light laser pointer beams aimed at commercial aircraft. Once we have located the x and y  coordinate bounding box for a laser beam of any intensity, could we subtract it out it's HSV (Hue, Saturation, Value) color components and convert it back to 24 bit RGB color space. Or could we just mask out the pixels corresponding to the location of the laser pointer ray?

Comment: Would you like to join our team of inventors who are working on weekends and holidays to commercialize a system for  filter visible light laser pointer beams aimed at commercial aircraft?

Comment: May I ask who manfactures the simpler detector screens that simply register basic intensity and peak color on each pixel? Does each pixel of your simpler detector screen have an analog to digital converter chip? Thanks

Comment: I don't know exact avail. parts, but was primarily looking at the 'apparent complexity' of a transparent sensor array capable of high-accuracy peak-wavelength/beam coherence detection vs. the 'apparently' simpler concept of detecting enough resolution to 'see' a spot that strikes both the inner & outer panes of the window with the same size/shape. For filtering/blocking the detected beam, I can imagine a few options, but don't think that comments here would be the best place for that discussion. ;-)